# Companies of users, model in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am just wondering how would design this in Firestore.
Let's say you have users collection. This collection has each user details such as birthday, email, name.. Etc.

Now let's say we have a  collection (company) that should have all the users  that work there.

How would you model that? 
Do you have a company collection with empty documents where each document has the id of the user.? Or do you duplicate all the user details under the documents inside companies?

I am just not able to get my head around  how Firestore can be modeled for these typical situations and not a lot of examples exist in docs to show you how use cases should be modeled

Thank you

Comment: You should look at it from the query(ies) you would like to execute on this data model.

Comment: This is where the problem is. If I set it up using the current queries I have and then I decide to add a  feature, it might make the whole model unusable.

Comment: For example, if I add documents under company collection and the document Contains last name attribute because that's what I want to display. Then I release the app and at a later point I decided to display email so now I have a to do migration to populate all the existing  documents with email addresses. So i was better off adding the userId in the first place. This is where I have issues with how to model

Comment: Actually, with NoSQL data modelling, you should not hesitate to duplicate data, i.e. to denormalize in such a way it makes your queries easier and, more important, faster. Have a look at this article: https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/

Comment: Thank you. I will check the link. The only issue with duplicating data is that if you ever decide to add functionality to change the data (say name of the user), then changing it across all collections and documents will be a huge integrity risk